# How do I get Mercurial's hgwebdir working on Windows?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

These are the steps I took:

- install apache 2.2.x
- install TortoiseHg 0.7
- copy hgwebdir.cgi, hgweb.config to cgi-bin
- edit hgweb.config as appropriate
- unzip $blah\TortoiseHg\library.zip to unzip $blah\TortoiseHg\library
- sys.path.append("$blah\TortoiseHg\library") at the beginning of
  hgwebdir.cgi
- move $blah\TortoiseHg\templates to $blah\TortoiseHg\library\templates

(Edit: I forgot to add that all these steps are laid out [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/HgWebDirStepByStep).)

When I run http://localhost/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi/ I can see my repository. If I try browse that repository, I'm told "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.". The last line of the walkback says "c:\program files\apache group\apache\cgi-bin\mercurial\osutil.pyc in __load()".

I've read about people having problems with pywintypes25.dll; this lives in "c:\program files\tortoisehg" and is already in my PATH.

What DLL couldn't be found?

Comment: Are you running on a 32 or 64bit machine?

Comment: 32-bit machine running XP. I have read elsewhere on SO of people having issues with 64-bit machines, but I can't find the reference now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you missed the c libs of mercurial

there are 3 ways to get out of this

1. recent mercurial versions ship with pure python implementations you can find in mercurial/pure
2. compile it yourself (im not exactly sure on the steps, on any unix this just works)
3. grab win32 installer from  [the website](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/BinaryPackages)
   note that i didn't yet take a look at how those are build
   (you need a distutils based install, not a py2exe based one)

Comment: This is using the win32 installer from the website. I can't import mercurial.osutil from inside a python REPL either (with the sys.path addition, of course).

Comment: I think the actual problem is that osutil.pyc is not compatible with your Python version, similar to the "Bad magic number" problem. Put the osutil.py from the pure directory in the mercurial directory, and the problem is gone. You could use the generated osutil.pyc then.

Answer (score 3):

First thing: don't use TortoiseHg for this. Use the Mercurial installer instead.

(TortoiseHg tries to be as independent of your Python installation as possible, and for reasons unclear to this Python-newbie, things Don't Work. Something about py2exe.)

Otherwise, just follow the steps in the HgWebDirStepByStep. I did have to install pywintypes, but YMMV. Lastly, the unzip utility mentioned on that page may do strange things with file permissions: I had to add read permissions to Templates directory and its files/subdirectories.

As an aside, if you're wondering how to set the style, add this to hgweb.config:

```
[web]
style = foo
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried lib from TortoiseHg, and it doesn't work. But when I used lib from Mercurial, everything worked.

Comment: Strangely, I had the exact opposite experience.

Answer (score 2):

My setup involves an apache 2.2.17, mod_wsgi 3.3, python 2.7.2, trac 0.12.2, mercurial 1.8.4. Two issues surfaced:

1. mercurial demandimport initialization order
2. mercurial unable to load DLLs in site-packages.

I solved the problem as follows:

1. change hgwebdir.wsgi to disable demandimport:

`from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.disable()`

2. create a pure (.py only, no compiled .pyd) mercurial package and install. See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WindowsInstall

`E:\Dist\mercurial-1.8.4>setup.py --pure build

E:\Dist\mercurial-1.8.4>setup.py --pure install`

The compiled versions (with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008) fail to load the DLL:

```
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24] mod_wsgi (pid=6092): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Home/web/apache/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.wsgi'.
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]   File "D:/Home/web/apache/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]     from mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod import hgwebdir
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]   File "C:\\Apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\hgweb\\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]     import hgweb_mod, hgwebdir_mod
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]   File "C:\\Apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\hgweb\\hgweb_mod.py", line 10, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]     from mercurial import ui, hg, hook, error, encoding, templater
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]   File "C:\\Apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\ui.py", line 10, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]     import config, util, error
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]   File "C:\\Apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\config.py", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]     import error, util
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]   File "C:\\Apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\util.py", line 17, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24]     import error, osutil, encoding
[Thu Jun 16 21:46:28 2011] [error] [client 192.168.178.24] ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is already answered, but I experienced a slightly different issue and found a work around --

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious in the Python configuration (2.5.4), but I'm having issues with .pyd versus .dll. (I had the same issues with the Python subversion libraries.) I see osutil.pyd in Mercurial\library.zip, but it fails to load it. Therefore, I unzipped library.zip and then copied *.pyd to *.dll, e.g:

```
REM Ugly DOS... Recursively renames all .pyd files to .dll
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.pyd') do copy "%%a" "%%~da%%~pa%%~na.dll"
```

Make sure the unzipped library directory is in the PYTHONPATH, but after this I successfully can execute: from mercurial import osutil. Also remember to copy or move the Templates directory to the newly unzipped library directory.

Follow the steps in Section 5 of the [HgWebDirStepByStep](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) for the rest. I did not experience the "Gotchas" in Section 5.3 though.