# How to serve my local Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I created a repository with TortoiseHg. Is it possible to share it with other machines? Or do I need to install another application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just share the folder and have the other machines push/pull.

You can also right-click your repo and choose "Web server" under the TortoiseHG menu. This serves the repo over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 7):

Right click your repository, TortoiseHG, Web Server menu option. That'll pop up a dialog, and you just hit the Start button.

Say your start port's 8000. Then on your other machines, right click in the folder where you want the new clone, select TortoiseHG, Clone a Repository. In the Source Path, put "http://originalmachine:8000/" and hit the "clone" button.

Web Server's great for temporary sharing. If you want something more persistent, that doesn't require a task sitting in your task bar, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644322/how-do-i-get-mercurials-hgwebdir-working-on-windows) for instructions on how to get hgwebdir set up on Windows (but this requires Mercurial, rather than TortoiseHg).